# conccurent access to instance variable in python

Tags: python, concurrency, instance-variables

I'm using tornado framework in python,

Here's a snippet of code which got me confused
Apparently when someone use the same piece of code my framework somehow shares all the self variables among different users which lead to concurrency issues

```
#!/usr/bin/python
class   MyClass:
    def __init__(self,env):
            self.path = '/some/path'

    def fucntion(self):
            self.path = '/some/other/path'
            print self.path
    def action(self):
            self.function()
```

If some user has called `action` function then all the other users will have the same value for self.path ('/some/other/path')

how can i get rid of the concurrency?

Comment: You need to use a separate instance of the class in each thread if you want them to not share state. How do you currently create the instance(s) of `MyClass`?

Comment: not sure, but the above code doesn't work for concurrent access, i go some advice to use global variables instead of instance variables, will that solve the purpose?